# How to compare two w_char[] strings

Tags: c, winapi

I want to check that an Edit Control only has HEX chars:

```
wchar_t valid_chars[] = {
    '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 
    'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 
    'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 
    0x08, 0x7f // backspace, del
};

wchar_t buf[80];  // store (wide) text from EDIT Control

GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_EDT_HEX, buf, 80);
```

So now the text from my Edit Control is stored in `buf`, how would I go about making sure that `buf` only contains characters from `valid_chars`?

**note**: the backspace, del chars in `valid_chars` are needed in another method which checks keystrokes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <cwchar>

wchar_t valid_chars[] = {
    L'0', L'1', L'2', L'3', L'4', L'5', L'6', L'7', L'8', L'9', 
    L'a', L'b', L'c', L'd', L'e', L'f', 
    L'A', L'B', L'C', L'D', L'E', L'F', 
    0x0008, 0x007f, // backspace, del
    0x0000
};

UINT len = GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_EDT_HEX, buf, 80);
for (UINT i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    if (std::wcschr(valid_chars, buf[i]))
        // is valid
    else
        // is not valid
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <algorithm>

wchar_t valid_chars[] = {
    L'0', L'1', L'2', L'3', L'4', L'5', L'6', L'7', L'8', L'9', 
    L'a', L'b', L'c', L'd', L'e', L'f', 
    L'A', L'B', L'C', L'D', L'E', L'F', 
    0x0008, 0x007f // backspace, del
};
wchar_t *valid_chars_end = &valid_chars[24];

UINT len = GetDlgItemText(hwnd, IDC_EDT_HEX, buf, 80);
for (UINT i = 0; i < len; ++i)
{
    if (std::find(valid_chars, valid_chars_end, buf[i]) != valid_chars_end)
        // is valid
    else
        // is not valid
}
```